# Finding area of hexagon inscribed in rectangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Question: A regular hexagon is inscribed in a rectangle as shown in the diagram below. The shaded areas are $20$ and $23$ each. Find the area of the regular hexagon.

I managed to deduce that the center of the hexagon is the same point as the center of the square using dilations.

Using this, since the diagram is symmetric, if $A_r$ represents the area of the rectangle and $A_h$ represents the area of the hexagon, then $$43+\frac{1}{2}A_h=A_r$$

From here, I know that I could solve the question by labeling a bunch of variables and using brute force, but I am looking for a cleaner solution. I think such a solution involves the fact that the hexagon can be split into six congruent equilateral triangles and adding them to the shaded regions. However, I am unsure to proceed (if this is even correct).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the labeled figure below.

[image]

It's very easy to show that $\angle BAG=90^{\circ}$. So, $\angle CBA=\angle FAG.$ Therefore, $\triangle CBA$ and $\triangle FAG$ are similar.

Now, let's assume the side of the regular hexagon is $a$. Then, $AG=a\sqrt 3.$

Consequently,

$$\frac{S_{\triangle FAG}}{S_{\triangle CBA}}=\frac{23+S_{\triangle DAG}}{20}=(\frac{a\sqrt 3}{a})^2 \implies S_{\triangle DAG}=37.$$

Moreover, one can easily prove that $S_{\triangle BAG}=2S_{\triangle DAG}$, and the final answer is $37 \times 6.$

We are done.